# A value is not returned to a parameter from ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: hana

The problem is as follows:
it is necessary to return a value from "select" to a parameter, but the provider for "ADO.NET" flies with an error. In "PostgreSQL" the value is returned to the parameters so (without specifying what, but simply in order), in "MsSQL" it would be necessary to "select" where my variables are needed via @. And how to do it in "Hana"? The search did not give information (it is necessary to return the value from the request, and not from the procedure).
This is how the error looks
[Provider Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRO5J.png)

Here is the code

```
        string sql = @"select id, json from pk5_app where kind = 'form' and code = 'mycode'";
        string cnStr = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("cnStr") as string;//Connection string here!
        int ResultInfo=-1;
        HanaParameter[] haparam = new HanaParameter[] {
            new HanaParameter() { ParameterName ="id", HanaDbType= HanaDbType.Integer, Direction=ParameterDirection.Output},
            new HanaParameter() { ParameterName ="json", HanaDbType= HanaDbType.NVarChar, Size=50, Direction=ParameterDirection.Output}
        };

        HanaConnection dbCnnHa = new HanaConnection(cnStr);
        dbCnnHa.Open();
        HanaTransaction trn = dbCnnHa.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        using (dbCnnHa)
        {
            HanaCommand sqlCmd = new HanaCommand(sql, dbCnnHa, trn);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(haparam);
            ResultInfo = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (param != null && param.Length > 0)
            trn.Commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered for a long time, but I made an example - now everything seems to be normal.

```
        string sql = @"do (OUT id integer=>?) begin select 5 into id from dummy; end;";
        string cnStr = "";//Connection string
        int ResultInfo = -1;
        HanaParameter haparam = new HanaParameter {
             ParameterName ="id", HanaDbType= HanaDbType.Integer, Direction=ParameterDirection.Output
        };

        HanaConnection dbCnnHa = new HanaConnection(cnStr);
        dbCnnHa.Open();
        HanaTransaction trn = dbCnnHa.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        using (dbCnnHa)
        {
            HanaCommand sqlCmd = new HanaCommand(sql, dbCnnHa, trn);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(haparam);
            ResultInfo = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trn.Commit();
        }
```